# How to set the timeout period on a JPA EntityManager query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, timeout, entitymanager

I'm currently getting connection timeout errors from my EntityManager queries. Is it possible to set a timeout for these?

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="CallPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>call.structure.Task</class>
    <class>call.structure.Installation</class>
    <class>call.structure.Contents</class>
    <class>call.structure.Recipient</class>
    <class>call.structure.CallTask</class>
    <class>call.structure.SmsTask</class>
    <class>call.structure.EmailTask</class>
    <class>call.security.User</class>
    <class>call.structure.content.Content</class>
    <class>call.structure.content.RecordContent</class>
    <class>call.structure.content.WaitContent</class>
    <class>call.structure.content.TextContent</class>
    <class>call.structure.content.VariableContent</class>
    <class>call.structure.content.SoundContent</class>
    <class>call.structure.content.SubjectContent</class>
    <class>call.structure.content.FileContent</class>
    <class>call.structure.Bounce</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:TEST"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="userpassword"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="username"/>
    </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Code times out in the run function of my thread:

```
private class TaskDB extends Thread {

    private final long WAITING_TIME = 20000L;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Set<SmsTask> remove = SMSManager.this.getRemoveTask();
        Set<SmsTask> normal = SMSManager.this.getNormalTask();

        try {
            while(true){
                EntityManager em = DB.getEM();  //Calls EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()
                em.getTransaction().begin();

                Set<SmsTask> normalClone = new HashSet<SmsTask>(normal);
                // Abort task in futur.
                List<SmsTask> taskToRemove = new ArrayList<SmsTask>();
                if (!remove.isEmpty()) {

                    String queryString = "SELECT t FROM SmsTask t WHERE t.id IN :remove ";
                    if (!normalClone.isEmpty())
                        queryString += "AND t.id NOT IN :normal ";

                    Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);
                    query.setParameter("remove", Utils.taskToIdList(remove));
                    if (!normalClone.isEmpty())
                        query.setParameter("normal", Utils.taskToIdList(normalClone));

                    taskToRemove = (List<SmsTask>) query.getResultList();
                    for (SmsTask task : taskToRemove) {
                        removedTask.add(task);
                        remove.remove(task);
                    }
                }

                String queryString = "SELECT t FROM SmsTask t WHERE (t.scheduleTime IS NULL OR t.scheduleTime < :dateNow) AND t.status = co.dium.call.structure.Task.StatusTask.NOT_START ";
                if (!taskToRemove.isEmpty())
                    queryString += "AND t.id NOT IN :toRemove ";

                Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);
                query.setParameter("dateNow", Utils.obtainUniversalTime());
                if (!taskToRemove.isEmpty())
                    query.setParameter("toRemove", Utils.taskToIdList(taskToRemove));
                List<SmsTask> taskResults = (List<SmsTask>) query.getResultList();

                em.getTransaction().commit();

                for (SmsTask task : taskResults) 
                    addTask(task);

                SMSManager.TaskRemove.sleep(WAITING_TIME);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SMSManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        System.out.println("Thread interrompu !");
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

The timeout errors that I get:

```
org.clipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O error: Socket read timed out
Error Code: 17002
Call: [....sql query...]
[...]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:742)
at call.manager.sms.SMSManager$TaskDB.run(SMSManager.java:367)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O Error: Scoket read timed out
[...]
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, there *javax.persistence.query.timeout*. According JPA 2.0 specification support for this query hint is optional:

> Portable applications should not rely on this hint. Depending on the
>   persistence provider and database in use, the hint may or may not be
>   observed.

Default value (in milliseconds) can be set to persistence.xml for all queries:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="1000"/>
```

Same property can be also given when creating EntityManagerFactory via Persistence.[createEntityManagerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29).

It can also be overridden/set per query:

```
query.setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 2000);
```

Same functionality can be obtained via attribute [hints](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html#hints%28%29) in NamedQuery.

Comment: seems the firewall was dropping the connection on long connections I needed to add to my persistence.xml:
javax.persistence.query.timeout (10000)
oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout (40000)
and (ENABLE=broken) in my tnsnames.ora
as well as modify the KeepAliveInterval and the KeepAliveTime in the windows registry

Comment: Though its an old question,I have similar issue while calling entitymanager.persist(). How can I set timeout property in such a case?

Comment: I also have same question, is there an easy way to set timeout on entitymanager.persist(). So far it seems the only option is to convert this to native insert sql statement.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways you can set up the query timeout period with Hibernate.

### The Hibernate-specific way

If you are bootstrapping Hibernate natively or if you are unwrapping the JPA `java.persistence.Query` to its `org.hibernate.query.Query` equivalent, then you can just use the `setTimeout` method:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "select p " +
    "from Post p " +
    "where lower(p.title) like lower(:titlePattern)", Post.class)
.setParameter("titlePattern", "%Hibernate%")
.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class)
.setTimeout(1)
.getResultList();
```

> Notice that the `setTimeout` method takes an `int` argument which specifies the timeout value in *seconds*.

### The JPA query hint way

You can also use a JPA query hint, as illustrated in the following example:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "select p " +
    "from Post p " +
    "where lower(p.title) like lower(:titlePattern)", Post.class)
.setParameter("titlePattern", "%Hibernate%")
.setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 50)
.getResultList();
```

> Notice that the [`javax.persistence.query.timeout`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-query-hints/) query hint takes the timeout value in *milliseconds*.

### The Hibernate query hint way

You can also use the `org.hibernate.timeout` query hint:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "select p " +
    "from Post p " +
    "where lower(p.title) like lower(:titlePattern)", Post.class)
.setParameter("titlePattern", "%Hibernate%")
.setHint("org.hibernate.timeout", 1)
.getResultList();
```

> Notice that the [`org.hibernate.timeout`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-query-hints/) query hint takes the timeout value in *seconds*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the query hint '`javax.persistence.query.timeout`', you should use '`javax.persistence.lock.timeout`'.

In the latter case, if the query does not return within the specified milliseconds you'll receive a `CannotAcquireLockException`. In the first case, if the transaction does not finish within the specified milliseconds, you'll receive a `QueryTimeoutException` and the transaction will be rolled back.

Comment: To elaborate, if you use `javax.persistence.query.timeout` you'll need to finish the complete transaction within the specified amount of milliseconds. If you use `javax.persistence.lock.timeout` only the lock should be acquired within the specified amount of milliseconds.