# EJB Transaction timeout for large volume data processing

Tags: transactions, timeout, ejb, jta

My application reads 50k to 100k records from one DB table and process the records in various stages by applying various formulas. We are using bean managed transactions. We need to create/update/delete the data in many tables. 
The process is started with

- EJB timer,
- reads data (around 50 K records data) from a table by joining with another table and insert the data in TEMP table (data is stored temporary)
- Read the TEMP data, apply some formulas on that data and insert data in multiple tables
- Data will be copied from this table to new table with joining additional tables for BI reports.

I am not setting any transaction time out in user transaction. I am using IBM web sphere App server.

Since the data is huge during formulas evaluation and some times when I am reading data from DB tables, I am getting transaction time out.

All the EJB's are stateless EJB's and Transaction is set is BEAN.

I separated the business logic and DB operations in separate methods.

I have not used any transaction for reading data from a table. But I still get transaction timeout exception when reading data without any transaction.

Please help me defining better approach and why I get TX timeout for reading data?

Comment: You could probably increase your query timeout. Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24249887/1346996) answer in order to solve your problem.

Comment: Normally, you set your default timeout in your persistence.xml file, but sometimes it isn't enough when the number of your records increase too much, I used ETL technologies in those cases... this is just an advice if you want to use it :)