# Timeout in JPA queries

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, settimeout, timeoutexception

I am using spring data jpa in our application.
I want to throw timeout exception, if database does not respond.
How can we set timeout in simple jpa queries, without using entity manager ?

Regards,
Stephan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the timeout period on a JPA EntityManager query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244621/how-to-set-the-timeout-period-on-a-jpa-entitymanager-query)

Comment: Hallo, thanks for your reply.                                                                                             I am not using entity manager. I am using simple JPA queries.                                                                                         In addition, am using spring boot with spring cloud connectors. Therefore, i tried with following:                                   
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout: 0
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-Timeout: 0 , but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout=60000` in `application.properties` ?

If your problem still exists try to add Spring Transaction annotation like the below code.

```java
@Transactional(timeout=10)
@Override
public List<EntityModel> function(EntityModel model) {

}
```