# Query timeout using setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 3000) is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MainDB")
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<Info> getData(String p1, String p2) {

        StoredProcedureQuery sp = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("myProc")
                .setParameter("p1", p1)
                .setParameter("p2", p2)
                .setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 3000);

        return (List<Info>) sp.getResultList();

  }
}
```

DB Configuration:

```
@Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", basePackages = {
    "com.mypackage.repository" })
    public class MainDBConfig {
    
        
        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "dataSource")
        @ConfigurationProperties
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }
        
        
        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
            HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    //      properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
            properties.put("hibernate.proc.param_null_passing", true);
            
            return builder.dataSource(dataSource).properties(properties)
                    .packages("com.mypackage.entity").persistenceUnit("MainDB").build();
        }
        
        
        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
                @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
        }
    }
```

changed my transaction manager to below but still does not work:

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    tm.setDefaultTimeout(3);
    return tm;
}
```

The stored procedure is still running after 3 seconds. My goal is to throw an exception if it exceeds 3 seconds and get the connection released back to the pool.

Spring Boot Version: 2.2.1.RELEASE,
Hibernate version: 5.4.8

Comment: Can you show us how you configure the 'PersistenceContext(unitName = "MainDB")'. I believe you need to define the 'javax.persistence.query.timeout' there initially and the setHint() then overrides this value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244621/how-to-set-the-timeout-period-on-a-jpa-entitymanager-query

Comment: updated my configuration.  Where should i set this?

Comment: updated my PlatformTransactionManager, set the timeout there, but it still does not work.

Comment: "Depending on the persistence provider and database in use, the hint may or may not be observed." - Which DB are you using?

Comment: I'm using Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 1):

i finally solved what i wanted to do by setting this property in application.yml:

spring.datasource.hikari.dataSourceProperties: oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=3000